# Php Docblocks @version $Id$ not working with NetBeans SVN Plugin

Tags: php, svn, netbeans, docblocks

For a project I'm working on we use SVN. So I installed the SVN Plugin for Netbeans, which works good so far.

Now in the classes and other php files we're using docblocks with @version tag. I'm wondering how I make the plugin to autofill / replace the $Id$ in the version tag?

I'm currently working with a Win7 & NetBeans 7.1.2. I added following lines to the config file under `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Subversion config`:

```
*.php = svn:keywords=Id
*.phtml = svn:keywords=Id
*.js = svn:keywords=Id
```

Also I removed the comment from following line:

```
enable-auto-props = yes
```

After a restart of NetBeans I noticed that the config file in (UserPath).netbeans\7.1.2\config\svn\config was updated with the previously added data.

But if I commit a changed file the @version tag is not updated. Only $Id$ remains right after. What am I doing wrong or did I missed to configure something?

It should look like this:

```
@version $Id: XYZ.php 637 2012-10-08 15:13:38Z flo $
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, or

- your config-changes doesn't play (create new file for testing)
- you forgot about auto-props one "small" detail - they applied to **new, created after enabling** files, not existing in repo. For these files you have to add svn:keywords by hand. Check with `svn proplist -v <FILENAME>`